How to sidestep of undifferentiability of Frobenius norm at 0 in the numerical analysis?
I am currently doing the  l-bfgs-b optimization algorithm. I have my objective function. I also need to get the gradient of the objective function. Some part of my objective function is Frobenius norm of a matrix A, that is denoted by $||A||_F$. I know the gradient of Frobenius norm of a matrix A is $\frac{A}{||A||_F}$. But I cannot directly put this into my optimization code in R, since it is not differentiable at $0$.
One very similar question is if some part of the objective function is $\ell_1$ norm of a matrix,  that is denoted by $||A||_1$. Then though it is also not differentiable at $0$, I can use some trick to transform equivalently to sidestep the indifferentiable issue. It can be referred here: Convert an optimization problem into box constraint
Do we have the similar trick to sidestep the indifferentiable issue of Frobenius norm?

A common way around this is to consider a regularized version of the square root that is differentiable:
$$
\mathcal{R}_\varepsilon (A) = \sqrt{\|A\|_F^2+\varepsilon} \\ \nabla \mathcal{R}_\varepsilon (A) = \frac{A}{\sqrt{\|A\|_F^2+\varepsilon}}.
$$
When $\|A\|_F \gg \varepsilon$, we have $\mathcal{R}_\varepsilon (A) = \|A\|_F + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$ and when $\|A\|_F \ll \varepsilon$, we have $\mathcal{R}_\varepsilon (A) = \sqrt{\varepsilon} + \frac{\|A\|_F^2}{2\sqrt{\varepsilon}} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\|A\|_F^4}{\varepsilon^{3/2}}\right)$. Therefore, it yields a good approximation for $A$ far from $0$ and reduces to a differentiable squared norm when $A$ is close to $0$.

Great. Is there any book or paper discussing this method?

Not to my knowledge, but it is pretty common in total variation regularization where one need to differentiate $\int_\Omega |\nabla u(x)|_2~\mathrm{d}x$ with respect to the function $u$
